# Метод родительского класса java не соглашается возвращать поле, переопределенное в дочернем классе

Tags: java, наследование

Есть простой код в котором мы переопределяем `int x` в дочернем классе :

```
class Parent { //родительский класс
     int x = 0; 
     public void printX() { //метод описанный только в родительском классе
          System.out.println(x); 
     } 
} 

public class Child extends Parent { //дочерний класс
    int x = -1; 
    public static void main(String... args) { 
       Child ch =  new Child();
       ch.printX();
    } 
}

OUTPUT: 0
```

Моё субъективное понимание языка в том, что мы создали объект дочернего (`Child`) класса. Значит поле у него `x = -1`, строка кода в мэйне

```
System.out.println(ch.x); //OUTPUT -1
```

полностью подтвердила мою гипотезу.
По моим понятиям у созданного объекта только одно поле `int x`, иначе была бы ошибка компиляции. Кроме того, я не создавал объект класса `Parent`, а значит нет другого объекта с полем `x = 0`;

**Вопросы:** почему метод `printX()` вывел нуль? Что это за поле родительского класса и где оно существует? Неужели это поле также создаётся в объекте дочернего класса? И опционально, какой логикой руководствовались создатели языка, делая наследование таким образом, что мне возвращается какое-то не очевидное значение, вместо того, чтобы вернуть значение дочернего класса?

Comment: Вы не переопределили поле, а добавили новое поле с таким же именем. Например, Netbeans IDE вам бы на такое пожаловался.

Comment: @ArchDemon Два поля с одним именем? А где ошибка компиляции?

Comment: переопределите в дочернем классе метод `printX()` и вы будете удивлены )))

Comment: А зачем вам ошибка компиляции? Почитайте http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/extends.php про ключевое слово `super`. На этой страницы точь в точь ваш пример рассмотрен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> почему метод printX() вывел нуль?

потому что, вы вызываете метод родителя, который выводит переменную x.

> Неужели это поле также создаётся в объекте дочернего класса?

когды вы написали

```
Child ch =  new Child()
```

проинициализились все поля родительского объекта.(И всех объектов в цепочке наследования)

> И опционально, какой логикой руководствовались создатели языка, делая наследование таким образом, что мне возвращается какое-то не очевидное значение, вместо того, чтобы вернуть значение дочернего класса?

Все логично, вы вызвали метод родителя он вернул переменую родителя.
Хотите что б вернул переменую дочернего класса, переопределяйте метод в классе Child

```
@Override
 public void printX() {
     System.out.println(x);
 }
```

Еще обращу ваше внимание на то что переменные в Java не полиморфны

```
class Parent { //родительский класс
    int x = 0;
    public int printX() { 
        return x;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int x = -1;    
    @Override
    public int printX() {
        return x;
    }   
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Parent ch = new Child();
        System.out.println(ch.printX()); // -1
        System.out.println(ch.x);        // 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Итого получается, поля родительского класса со схожими названиями тоже существуют в объекте, просто по дефолту перекрылись полями дочернего класса?

Comment: будет здорово если поправите вёрстку. >Цитировать нужно тэгом '>' а не `кодовой разметкой`.

Comment: Правильние было бы сказать что класс наследник скрыл поля класса родителя.

Comment: Верстка понятие типографское

Comment: Ну да, спасибо разобрался. Завтра чуть-чуть подправлю ваш ответ, ибо вы всё понимаете, только объясняете пока что не самым лучшим образом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалить `x`, определенную в `Child` и тогда все будет работать:

```
Child obj = new Child();
obj.x = -1;
obj.printX();
```

Дело в том, что вы вызывается переменную `x`, которая на привязана к `Child`, т.е. вы ее перекрыли.

Но если необходимо перекрыть используете ключевое слово super и вызовите вариант из суперкласса:

```
super.x = 12;
```